# Replace noisy input in list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list like that:

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

how can I filter it in such a way that noisy input (like the 2, here) is replaced by the neighbouring values, like that:

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CommonestFilter[list, 3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

or

```
MedianFilter[list, 3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Also

```
SequenceReplace[list, {x_,y_,x_}/; y!=x:>Sequence[x,x,x]]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @james, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.